# How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?

Tags: applications, nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

I created a new user in Nexus 7 but it doesn't have any applications already installed in primary user. I don't want to move/share any app data like scores/progress. I want the apps/games to appear as newly installed in new user. The reason for this is to create a guest user so that I can safely give my tablet to friends/kids who just want to play games.

Answer (score 3):

If your device is rooted, you might want to take a look at [Multi-User App Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivehellions.android.muappshare). This app permits the owner to "share" installed apps with other users (which shares the apps only, not their data), so they don't need to be installed again. According to the app description and comments, this even works for paid apps (at least partly -- this feature is not yet fully tested).

For the other part (without root), see the [answer of Penguinolog](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33830/16575).

Answer (score 3):

If you have root, I have created an app – [AppShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spectrl.appshare) – that will do exactly what you want, similar to the app suggested by Izzy but a bit more polished and user-friendly (at least I think so!).

Paid apps will most likely require you to add the Google account that you purchased the app with to the secondary (guest) account or else they will probably fail the licence check. This may vary from app to app though.

You will have no problems with free apps though, and you should even be able to disable system apps such as Gmail etc.

Answer (score 2):

If application installed to you main profile, install on second profile will be with fake downloaded, but second profile requires market.

If second account hasn't market, you can manually backup apks to PC and install to second user, but it's illegal for payed apps and some apps will not work because of license issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the new profile and enter play store...hit the top left 'play store 'icon go to my apps.... scroll to the one you want ..hit it and it gives the option to install.. hope this helps... took me ages to work it out.. :-)