# Using the same apps for a second user in Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/how-to-migrate-applications-to-other-user-account-without-downloading-the-applic)

I've created a second user on my Nexus 7 for my wife.

Do I have to re-install common apps like Facebook and Skype for the second user?

Can I not just bring the apps across from the first user?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities with Android 4.2. The "board methods" are, as already explained in other answers: Every user has to **install** each app he wants to use (aside from the pre-installed ones) -- but they will be downloaded only once. Now, if one user updates the app, it will be updated for the other user(s) as well (which might get a bit problematic if one user does *not* want a certain app to be updated -- but that's up to the users to make clear).

If root is available on the device, some other interesting options pop up -- for which you might want to take a look at:

[How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/16575)

With root, you can share apps (not data, of course) among users without the need of re-installation using [Multi-User App Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivehellions.android.muappshare), which even is reported to (partially?) work with paid ones.

Comment: Regarding the root options available, see my answer here also: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38529/27466

Answer (score 0):

From a system perspective, no, you don't need to reinstall.  You might have Each user has their own settings for those apps.

Comment: I have a Nexus 7 with multiusers. Each user has it's own apps. No global apps. I'd like to know if such a thing is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You must reinstall them, but not re-download them.
Apps that download external content will most likely have to download it for every user. For example, Dead Space.